# Compute $P(Y−X<1)$

Tags: probability

Let $X∼N(2,2)$ be independent of $Y ∼N(4,3)$. Compute $P(Y−X<1)$.

I can recall $Z=Y-X$, so I have to find $P(Z<1)$ where Z has a Normal Distribution $Z∼N(4-2,3-2)=N(2,1)$, where $\mu=2$ and $\sigma^2=1$. 
So I $P(Y−X<1)=P(Z<\frac{1-2}{\sqrt{1}})=P(Z>1)=0.158$ (from the $N(0,1)$ tables). 
But for the solution the correct result should be 0.327, where is my mistake? Thank you!

Comment: Is it really correct to subtract one variance from the other ?

Comment: The variance of the difference of two independent normally distributed random variables is not the difference of their variances. (If you had applied the argument to $X - Y$, you would have gotten a negative variance!)

Comment: You are right, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variance of $Z$ is sum of the variances of $X$ and $Y$, not the difference. Now redo your calculations and you will get the correct answer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, not it's clear!